# Documentation for vim help file markup

Tags: vim, markup

Is there a complete source of documentation on the markup format used in vim help files?  `:help write-local-help` provides some info but does not, for example, document the markup used to indicate quoted sections.

*update*: I've also discovered [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_use/msg/2791367997058fa4) on the vim-use mailing list which provides slightly more info than the afore-mentioned help entry.

Answer (score 7):

It seems everyone still sticks to reading another help file or reading the syntax file.

I did find the following two additional references:

- [Learn Vimscript The Hard Way: Documentation](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/54.html)
- `:help help-writing`

Comment: The "Learn Vimscript The Hard Way: Documentation" link is excellent... just what the doctor ordered!

Answer (score 4):

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/help.vim
```

This will indicate you how vim colours its own help files.

```
:help write-local-help
```

will also show you an example.

Comment: I'm hoping to find a reference similar to the one you (and I) mentioned, but more thorough.  The help syntax file is certainly thorough, but reading a set of regular expressions is not generally the best way to learn how to write markup.  Also, if there *is* an authoritative reference, the syntax colouring code may change in future vim versions in ways that still honour that reference.

Comment: OP specifically said that file is not helpful